# segmentation fault (core dumped) - what is wrong in my code

Tags: c, unix, gcc, segmentation-fault

Somebody knows why I get the message "segmentation fault (core dumped)"? What is wrong? It seems to me that the problem is with an array. I know that "Segmentation fault" means that I tried to access memory that I do not have access to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int shmid;
    int i, j;
    int glos;
    pid_t pid;
    key_t key;
    long *wyniki;

    key = ftok("/home/sebastian", 2);

    shmid = shmget(key, 20 * sizeof(long), IPC_CREAT);

    if (shmid == -1) {
        printf("Error - New memory segment");
    }
    else {
        printf("My memory segment: %d\n", shmid);
        wyniki = (long*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            wyniki[i] = 0;
        }

        // Creating new processes
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                srand48(time(NULL) + getpid());
                for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                    glos = rand() % 5;
                    wyniki[glos] += 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("ERROR - PROCESSES");
            }
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use gdb?  What were the values of the variables before the seg fault?  Does `ftok` succeed?  You should [check its return value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftok.html#tag_03_198_04) just in case.

Comment: compile the program with -g, run its using gdb, this will show you the line it is failingon

Comment: `ftok` no returns -1.

Comment: what header files did you #include?

Comment: debugger says there is no such file or directory in ftok. In addition, throws segmentation fault when I want to reset array `wyniki`

Comment: for readability by us humans, please indent the code consistently.  typically indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   Never use tabs to indent because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces for indenting as that allows several indent levels across the page and is wide enough to be visible even with a variable width font

Comment: @user3629249 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Comment: here is an excerpt of the man page for `ftok()`:  "The ftok() function uses the identity of the file named  by  the  given
       pathname  (which  must  refer  to an existing, accessible file) and the
       least significant 8 bits of proj_id (which must be nonzero) to generate
       a  key_t  type  System  V  IPC  key,  suitable  for use with msgget(2),
       semget(2), or shmget(2)."   Notice that part "must  refer  to an existing, accessible file"   however, the "/home/sebastian" is very likely to be a directory, not a file

Comment: on linux, for the `srand48()` need to have `#define _SVID_SOURCE`   or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`  before any of the #include statements.    The posted code is not using the parameter: `argc` nor the parameter: `argv[]`  each of which will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Suggest: `int main( void )`

Comment: your comment says #include 8 header files, but the latest posted code is only including 5 header files

Comment: the call to `fork()` can have three kinds of return conditions.  1) ==0 means in the child process.  2) >0 means in the parent process and 3) <0 means an error occurred.   The posted code is displaying an error message when in the parent process and the call to `fork()` was successful.   Always a very good idea to read/understand the man page for any system function that is called in the code

Comment: this line: `printf("Error - New memory segment");` should be calling `perror()` rather than `printf()` so 1) the output goes to stderr and 2) the appropriate system error message is also output

Comment: regarding the contents of this loop: `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)`,  the child must not continue around the loop,  otherwise the child will again call fork() which the resulting child process will again call fork(), etc.   So the first parent calls `fork()` 20 times and each of the parent children calls `fork()` 19 times and each childs child calls `fork()` 18 times, etc.   the result will be 20 factorial processes.  I.E. 2.432 902 008 18e+18 processes!  Probably not what you want

Comment: @user3629249 Exactly this is happening. I need to fix a problem with this fork (). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the shared memory segment without properly setting the permission bits, so you don't have access to the memory.

Per the `shmget()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html):

> ```
>    int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
>    ...
>    In addition to the above flags, the least significant 9 bits of
>    shmflg specify the permissions granted to the owner, group, and
>    others.  These bits have the same format, and the same meaning, as
>    the mode argument of open(2).  Presently, execute permissions are not
>    used by the system.
> ```

You need to specify the permissions for the shared memory segment:

```
shmid=shmget(key, 20 * sizeof(long), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
```

Or use `0640`, `0660` or symbolic modes.

But first you'll probably have to remove the existing segment using `ipcrm`.

Comment: So that was the reason. But shmget gives me -1 value. It is related to an existing segment?

Comment: @Se-BASS-tian Possible.  Look at the output from `ipcs -m`, and remove all the segments that are owned by your account, assuming you're not running as root and there aren't a bunch of other shared memory segments that exist for other purposes.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html

Answer (score 0):

to fix the `too many processes created problem:

change this:

```
    // Creating new processes
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            srand48(time(NULL) + getpid());
            for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                glos = rand() % 5;
                wyniki[glos] += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR - PROCESSES");
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
    // Creating new processes
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) 
        { // child process
            srand48(time(NULL) + getpid());
            for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) 
            {
                glos = rand() % 5;
                wyniki[glos] += 1;
            }
            exit();
        }

        else if( 0 > pid)
        { // error occurred
            perror( "fork() failed" );
            printf("ERROR - PROCESSES\n");
        }

        //else
        //{ // parent process
        //    ; 
        //}
    } // end: for 20 child processes
```

Comment: I fixed it a few hours ago, exactly the same as now written :)